# Converting an entity to an enum and vice versa in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Scenario:Let us assume a unidirectional relationship A->ManyToOne->B ( hence 2 tables A and B) in JPA. Typically, this will be mapped in Entity A as:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
B b;
```

Table A will hence contain a foreign key which will be primary key in Table B.

Further, let us assume that B is a table that contains static values.
In JPA the  * -> One mappings are eager by default. To avoid an extra query, I can always do a join fetch to avoid the extra query.
I understand how enums can be used/converted to store a column value in a table.

Questions:

1. Would it really be a value addition to have an enum representation
   for the static values when we already have a table and hence an
   entity for table B?
2. If we do have an enum,is it possible to convert the entity B to an
   enum (representing static values)  and vice versa? I have usually
   seen enum converted into a column in table and not a complete
   entity/row in a table.
3. Even if the above works and we want to retrieve A and B, can the
   enum be used to avoid the extra join (without the fetch join) while
   doing the conversion?

Comment: enum in JPA is a column. Nothing more to say. Would be more efficient to use an enum than having to join to get values

Comment: @NeilStockton, what you are suggesting is getting rid of the table B and rather have a column in table A which holds static values in the enum ?

Comment: The "lookup" would be in the Java enum class. The table A would have either the string or ordinal of the enum. I'm not suggesting anything, just that it would be more efficient to do that than have this extra table. Your choice.